# Can anyone find and help me what is this error is about?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-8

```
@foreach($id_cards as $id_card)
    <option value="{{$id_card->id}}" {{isset($card_id) ? ($id_card->id == $card_id ? 'selected': old("id_card") == $id_card->id ? "selected":""):""}}>{{$id_card->title}}</option>
@endforeach
```

error is:
"Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

Comment: Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is clearly saids that you should add additional parenthesis here:

```
$id_card->id == $card_id ? 'selected': old("id_card") == $id_card->id ? "selected":""
```

to for example:

```
$id_card->id == $card_id ? 'selected': (old("id_card") == $id_card->id ? "selected":"")
```

As you can read in [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> It is recommended to avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious compared to other languages. Indeed prior to PHP 8.0.0, ternary expressions were evaluated from left to right, instead of right to left like most other programming languages.